# Python: How to print date format with using the help function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, parameters, strftime

I would like to print the date format so I dont need to search in the navigator every time I want to print a date like in the following code:

```
time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print("time:", time)
```

I been searching and didn't find any thing about this.

When you run `help(the_date.strftime)`, it doesn't show the possible parameters.

Comment: `..dont need to search in the navigator..` - add a link to your browser favorites - `https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior`

Answer (score 1):

You can see the format codes here - [Basic date and time types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

The below sample reference:

```
     import time
    print("time:{}".format(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```